# Advice on running random forests on a large dataset

Tags: r, random-forest, large-data, computational-statistics

I am planning to run random forests to predict a binary outcome. I have a relatively (from my point of view) large dataset, composed of 500,000 units and around 100 features (a mix of continuous, binary and categorical variables). I am planning to use the `rf` package from the `caret` library in `R`.

I used to run random forests on smaller datasets on my personal laptop or on a small AWS-EC2. 
Any advice on how to run it efficiently in terms of computational power? For instance,

- if I opt for an AWS-EC2 server, which one should I use?
- Should I consider using [SparkR](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/sparkr/overview.html) (a frontend for Spark on R)?
- Should I consider parallel computing?
- How much time should I expect the algorithm to obtain a solution?

Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 9):

Some hints:

- 500k rows with 100 columns do not impose problems to load and prepare, even on a normal laptop. No need for big data tools like spark. Spark is good in situations with hundreds of millions of rows.
- Good random forest implementations like `ranger` (available in `caret`) are fully parallelized. The more cores, the better.
- Random forests do not scale too well to large data. Why? Their basic idea is to pool a lot of very deep trees. But growing deep trees eats a lot of resources. Playing with parameters like `max.depth` and `num.trees` help to reduce computational time. Still, they are not ideal. In your situation, maybe 20 minutes with `ranger` on a normal laptop would be sufficient. (A rough guess).

```
    library(ranger)
    n <- 500000
    p <- 100
    df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(n * p), ncol = p))
    df$y <- factor(sample(0:1, n, TRUE))
    object.size(df) # 400 MB

    head(df)

    fit <- ranger(y ~ ., 
                  data = df, 
                  num.trees = 500,
                  max.depth = 8,
                  probability = TRUE)
    fit
```

[image]

With higher `max.depth`, quite a lot of additional time will be required.

Comment: Thanks so much Michael! More generally what classifier would you suggest in case of large data?

Comment: It depends very much on the situation and the data structure. Furthermore, an appropriate train/validation/test strategy is of major importance. All plays together very closely, so the best algorithm might fail if data is ill-prepared or the train/valid/test strategy is bad.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is already given in the other answer (+1), the dataset you describe is not that big and should not need any specialized software or hardware to handle it. The only thing that I'd add, is that you rather **should not use Spark**. You can check [those benchmarks](https://github.com/szilard/benchm-ml), Spark "is slower and has a larger memory footprint" and for some versions of Spark "random forests having low prediction accuracy vs the other methods", so basically, the Spark implementation of random forest is poor.

Comment: Just to add insult to injury here: Spark's MLlib random forests are constrained to [max depth of 30](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ca6955858cec868c878a2fd8528dbed0ef9edd3f/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala#L137).

Comment: well, it's very unusual to have a RF depth of more than 30 (especially with a dataset that small). If you needed depth >30 (image classification/segmentation maybe?) it's usually a sign that RF is a poor method and something else would work better.